# Como usar ClassLoader.getResources() corretamente em Java?

Tags: java, resources

Eu não estou conseguindo capturar o caminho certo donde está meu arquivo CSV através dessa linha de código abaixo utilizando **ClassLoader.getResources()**;

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class IndicioActionTest {

    public File getFile(String nomeArquivo) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL resource = classLoader.getResource("csvs/" + nomeArquivo);
        return new File(resource.getPath());
    }
}
```

A construção do algoritmo está errado porque a variável **resource** está vendo nula.

O meu arquivo está aqui;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Gostaria de adiantar que essa postagem não é duplicata, porque semana passado postei algo semelhante!*

Estou precisando implementar um teste unitário de um recurso da aplicação que se trata de um upload de arquivos **CSV**, com isso tenho que capturar várias informações do arquivo, na primeira vezes que fiz a postagem na busca de esclarecer dúvidas, foi me orientado aqui pelo StackOverFlow de desacoplar mais o método responsável em fazer o upload de arquivo CSV, e foi exatamente o fiz.

Preciso implementar um teste unitário desse método.

```
public String uploadArquivo() {

        try {

            removeInSession(LISTA_TIPO_INDICIOS);
            removeInSession(LISTA_INDICIOS);
            removeInSession(LISTA_ERRO);

            final File arquivoLeitura = new File(getArquivo());

            final LineNumberReader linhaLeitura = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(arquivoLeitura));
            linhaLeitura.skip(arquivoLeitura.length());
            final int qtdLinha = linhaLeitura.getLineNumber() + 1;

            final BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getArquivo())));

            String linha = null;

            leitor.readLine();

            for (int indiceIndicio = 2; indiceIndicio <= qtdLinha; indiceIndicio++) {
                statusMatricula = false;
                linha = leitor.readLine();

                if (linha == null) {
                    break;
                }

                final String[] dadosCSV = linha.split(VIRGULA);
                final int numberPositions = dadosCSV.length;

                setNumberPositions(numberPositions);

                boolean resultValidation = false;

                resultValidation = verificadorFluxoCSV(dadosCSV);

                if (getNumberPositions() <= 6) {
                    if (resultValidation) {
                        erroCSVList = ErroCSV.verificarErros6Linhas(dadosCSV, tipoIndicio, uJ, naturezaIndicio,
                                expressaoInvalida, validadorCPF, erroCSVList, indiceIndicio);
                        addInSession(LISTA_ERRO, erroCSVList);

                    } else {
                        verificarListaIndicios(listaTotalIndicio, listaIndicioEntity, uJ, tipoIndicio, dadosCSV);
                    }
                } else if (getNumberPositions() > 6 && getNumberPositions() < 13) {
                    if (resultValidation) {

                        erroCSVList = ErroCSV.verificarErros12Linhas(dadosCSV, tipoIndicio, uJ, naturezaIndicio,
                                expressaoInvalida, validadorCPF, erroCSVList, indiceIndicio, dataValidaEncontrada,
                                tipoVinculo, usuarioCorporativo);
                        addInSession(LISTA_ERRO, erroCSVList);

                    } else {
                        verificarListaIndicios(listaTotalIndicio, listaIndicioEntity, uJ, tipoIndicio, dadosCSV);
                    }
                } else if (getNumberPositions() >= 13) {

                    if (resultValidation) {

                        erroCSVList = ErroCSV.verificarErros12Linhas(dadosCSV, tipoIndicio, uJ, naturezaIndicio,
                                expressaoInvalida, validadorCPF, erroCSVList, indiceIndicio, dataValidaEncontrada,
                                tipoVinculo, usuarioCorporativo);

                        addInSession(LISTA_ERRO, erroCSVList);

                    } else {
                        verificarListaIndicios(listaTotalIndicio, listaIndicioEntity, uJ, tipoIndicio, dadosCSV);

                    }

                }

            }

            leitor.close();

        } catch (

        final FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error(e);
            erroInterno();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            logger.error(e);
            erroInterno();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return PAGE_IMPORTAR;
    }
```

Para implementar os testes unitário do upload de arquivos, é uma boa prática invés de utilizar o arquivo de upload em tempo de execução, é colocar o arquivo CSV dentro da própria aplicação e depois implementar a classe de teste.
Eu coloquei dentro desse caminho;

```
/src/test/resources/csvs/
```

O resultado esperado tem que ser semelhante a esse na classe de testes;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentativas realizadas=======================================================

```
@Test
public void verificadorFluxoCSVTest() throws IOException {
    String caminho = new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "\\resources\\csvs\\teste.csv";

    final LineNumberReader linhaLeitura = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(caminho));

    linhaLeitura.skip(caminho.length());
    final int qtdLinha = linhaLeitura.getLineNumber() + 1;

}
```

Conseguir resolver parcialmente meu problema, só não ficou completamente certo porque a variável caminho tem que ser um *File* e não uma *String*.

Tentei fazer a modificação, mas tive sucesso;

Comment: Como está chamando o `getFile`? Poste o código desta parte do teste ou do teste inteiro. Da forma como mostrou, o problema poderia ser simplesmente o nome do arquivo errado passado para o getFile.

Comment: Eu fiz uma modificações e uns testes na minha classe , e tive sucesso, como pode ver na minha postagem, eu fiz uma atualização, o problema é que eu fiz o caminho como se fosse uma variável String, mas ela tem que ser um a variável do tipo File, eu tentei fazer umas modificações, mas gera erros, falta muito pouco para concluir, ainda preciso de ajuda.